# android:ellipsize="end" not working in preferences.xml

Tags: android

Can anyone help me with this ?

The string in preference.xml is not showing any effect after setting the attribute to android:ellipsize="end" .

```
     <PreferenceCategory 
    android:key="pref_key_mms_settings"
              android:title="@string/pref_mms_settings_title" 
              android:ellipsize="end" >

    <CheckBoxPreference android:defaultValue="false"

        android:key="pref_key_mms_delivery_reports"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_mms_delivery_reports"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_mms_delivery_reports" />

    <CheckBoxPreference android:defaultValue="false"

        android:key="pref_key_mms_read_reports"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_mms_read_reports"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_mms_read_reports" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:ellipsize` is defined e.g. for TextView but not for `PreferenceCategory`.